# Why is document.cookie is not getting set in new tab page console?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, cookies

I ran these following commands in console of new tab page.

[image]

As you can see, the cookie is not storing any info. Why is this?

Comment: could there already be a `test` cookie? also works in safari 15.2 for me

Comment: do you have cookies disabled?

Comment: Probably not a real webpage. You are on a new tab start page, not google.com. `console.log(window.location.href)` will result in not an http result.

Comment: It doesn't work because you are not _on_ any domain, you are just looking at the chrome start page - so there is nothing to store the cookie _for_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not on https://google.com. You are on a browser page (aka `about:`). Those are special.